# JSON different objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am using the code below in order to create an object (below):

```
            var data3 = [];
            data3.push('{"headers":["Dimension 1","Metric 1","Metric 2"],"rows":[');
            for (var i in results.data)
            {
                object =  '["'+ results.data[i].Country +'",'+ results.data[i].Price +','+ results.data[i].Discount+'],';
                data3.push(object);
            }
            data3.push(']}');
```

What I am trying to return is the following object:

```
  var json_data= {"headers":["Dimension 1","Metric 1","Metric 2"],"rows":[["Australia",174,23],["Canada",502,17],["France",242,37],["Germany",102,42],["United Kingdom",126,44],["United States",1246,47],["Australia",680,80],["Canada",1241,66],["Canada",1241,66],["France",150,30],["Germany",244,22],["United Kingdom",501,9],["United States",4960,41],["Australia",9,8],["Canada",3655,70],["France",1654,95],["Germany",1190,36],["United Kingdom",1222,38],["United States",7941,53],["Australia",6829,56],["Canada",1664,75],["France",2995,88],["Germany",1487,100],["United Kingdom",9245,29],["United States",9008,66],["Australia",9376,7],["Canada",1531,31],["France",5421,22],["Germany",6975,41],["United Kingdom",4320,100],["United States",3200,41],["Australia",6688,41],["Canada",699,42],["France",5403,70],["Germany",6377,49],["United Kingdom",2471,14],["United States",6650,4],["Australia",865,70],["Canada",511,20],["France",981,36],["Germany",57,10],["United Kingdom",675,38],["United States",40,72],["Australia",400,63],["Canada",971,90],["France",357,93],["Germany",820,40],["United Kingdom",520,32],["United States",448,24],["Australia",513,40],["Canada",977,8],["France",118,84],["Germany",161,29],["United Kingdom",239,89],["United States",327,79]]};
```

How can I create the object without having to convert to a string?

Comment: You are creating an array of Strings. Disregarding what an antipattern it is to create objects that way, you'd have to compose a single string instead., then call `JSON.parse()` on it (assuming it's calid JSON).

Comment: @ChrisG In the console, both types are objects. I cannot use a string as I want to use `var platform_data = json_data.rows;` afterwards.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer in js arrays are objects too (`typeof []` returns `"object"`)

Comment: I have tried JSON.parse() for that reason.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer The first console output you're showing is an array containing 57 strings. In theory you could turn that into the desired object using `JSON.parse(data3.join(""))` but that is an extreme antipattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from `results.data` you can just rearrange stuff and build new Objects without ever descending into String hell.

Use `Array.map()` to turn the server response into the desired rows array, then compose a new Object:

```js
const results = {
  data: [{
      Country: "Australia",
      Price: 174,
      Discount: 23
    },
    {
      Country: "Canada",
      Price: 502,
      Discount: 17
    },
    {
      Country: "France",
      Price: 242,
      Discount: 37
    }, {
      Country: "Germany",
      Price: 102,
      Discount: 42
    }
  ]
}

const rows = results.data.map(row => [row.Country, row.Price, row.Discount]);

var data3 = {
  "headers": ["Dimension 1", "Metric 1", "Metric 2"],
  "rows": rows
};

console.log(data3);
```

Comment: That worked. Easy and fast. I had a script converting everything into a string. That was a bad decision.